# Alternatives to typed datasets?

Tags: c#, ado.net, dataset, business-objects

I can add a stored procedure to a dataset and handle the data manipulation.

Wanted to know if there are any other ways through which on the basis of stored procedure result sets, I can handle data in the BAL, like dynamically generating business objects or something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for an [ORM (Object-relational mapping) engine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping), such as [Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/aa937723.aspx) or [NHibernate](http://nhforge.org).

Comment: ^^ but doesn't an ORM engine directly interacts with the data, I mean ain't it creates the queries on its own?

Comment: @Dienekes: Most ORMs, including both EF and NHibernate, can be configured to use stored procedures instead.